# Is pdflscape incompatible with atbegshi or TikZ? Possible cause of Error 14 in Adobe Acrobat [XeTeX]

Tags: xetex, incompatibility, landscape, atbegshi

I am going nuts trying to figure out two issues that may be related.

- The first one is the fact that a `\AtBeginShipout` from `atbegshi` "seems" to be called twice on the first page, because the opacity is lost on the `tikz` drawing when used in combination with `pdflscape`.
- The second is the error message I get when I open the PDF with Adobe Acrobat 8 and sometimes Adobe Reader X (My minimal version of the code seems to work with Reader, but my real version definitely has issues with both.)

## Code

I compile with `xelatex`. As mentioned in the comments, this seems to make a difference in the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % Commenting out this package results in TikZ drawing the its overlay once on the first page as it should.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{atbegshi} 

\newcommand\qikofficialbuild{false}

\NewDocumentCommand{\qikdraftpage}{ }{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
    \draw [red,line width=2pt,opacity=0.1,text=gray,font=\bfseries] ([xshift=-4mm]current page.south west) -- ([xshift=-4mm]current page.north east) node [pos=.75,below, sloped] {UNOFFICIAL DRAFT \quad---\quad Typeset on \today{} with XeLaTeX};
    \draw [red,line width=2pt,opacity=0.1] ([xshift=4mm]current page.south west) -- ([xshift=4mm]current page.north east);
  }%
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}[2][]{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]%
        \node [font=\Huge] at (current page.center) {#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
}%


% Finalize Shipout
\IfEq{\qikofficialbuild}{false}{%
        \AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{\qikdraftpage}}
    }%
    {}%

\begin{document}
\maketitle{Title of this Document}
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "called twice"?

Comment: @egreg See the stripes on the maketitle page. They are not darker from `tikz` opacity. They are actually drawn twice.

Comment: The stripes are not drawn twice. You wouldn't such a dark color only by drawing your stripes again. But somehow the opacitiy setting is lost. I get the correct opacitiy by adding `,opacity=1` to the maketitle picture. (opacity is rather curious, it has a tendency to leak out of boxes).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You must compile with xelatex to see the problem. With pdflatex everything is fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh thanks, the question could have mentioned that:-)

Comment: Well the stripe says "Typeset on \today{} with XeLaTeX". I took this as a hint ...

Comment: with xetex I see darker stripes and xpdf reports eight instances of `Syntax Error: ExtGState 'pgf@CA0.1' is unknown`

Comment: The problem with the darker stripes is not directly caused by pdflscape but the package loads `atbegshi` too, and so atbegshi is now loaded *before* tikz (which loads everyshi, and does some also some patching). If you move pdflscape behind tikz, it works again. It also works if you load everyshi before pdflscape so that atbegshi can patch it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry everybody. I was out and about. Thanks for the xelatex comment. I was not aware that there would be a difference. I usually put `\usepackage{fontspec}` in my code to make that apparent. I will update my question to reflect that. Haha, I just noticed the "hint". Good eye. Take that, David Carlisle :) I should also mention that the darker stripes are the least of my worries. The major issue for me is Error 14 in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For the record, I resituated `àtbegshi ` after `tikz`, and my minimal example worked as expected. But, my actual document (that loads many packages) did not. My first step would be to move `tikz` to an early part of the preamble in front of most other packages. This method would leave me wondering which other package(s) was(were) the culprit(s). I could just keep deleting packages (a time-consuming venture) until it works. Is there a better way? How would you go about efficiently determining whether `atbegshi` is loaded by other packages?

Comment: I would look in the log-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments above (particular Ulrike Fischer's), TikZ is compatible with `pdflscape`. It is just that the order in which the packages are loaded is important, because `tikz` applies a patch to `everyshi` (and also `atbegshi` because it is an extension of `everyshi`). `pdflscape` loads `atbegshi`, therefore it is important to load it after `tikz` to ensure that the `atbegshi` part is patched.

## Summary:

Any package that loads `everyshi` or `atbegshi` should be loaded **after** `tikz`. Not doing this can cause Adobe Acrobat to give *Error 14* when mixing unpatched and patched `everyshi`/`atbegshi`.